# Hyphenating a compound word that is space separated

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated, suspended-hyphen

I have the two concept *antibody* and *metal ion* and I would like to pair them with *conjugated*.

In the first case I would use *antibody-conjugated*.
What's the correct typesetting in the second case?

Is it *metal ion-conjugated* or *metal-ion-conjugated*?

Comment: I'd use antibody-conjugated only when I placed it before a noun. But if the noun is antibody conjugated, no hyphen. Either way, I'd hyphenate a metal-ion conjugated thing.

Comment: You've got to disambiguate where necessary, and you've got dashes as well as hyphens to help with this (according to Wikipedia and various style guides). _Deciding where it's necessary is the hard bit._ // Here, it's tempting to use square brackets: [metal ion] [conjugated] ... which sadly no style guide allows for this purpose. Now hyphens imply connection in the first instance, so I'd avoid _metal ion-conjugated_. If you wish to preserve the connector before _connected_ in prenominal usage, you could add a dash as a 'weaker hyphen':  _metal-ion–conjugated_ (using the en- or  em-dash).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes, thank you!